# Android WebView html href value format

Tags: android

I have a webview in my Fragment. An HTML string is loaded to it. The string contains the link tag: `"<a href="anyText">anyText</a>"`
Then I set a webviewclient for my webview.

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            // you tell the webclient you want to catch when a url is about to load
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView  view, String  url){
                Logger.d("url="+url);

                return true;
            }
            // here you execute an action when the URL you want is about to load
            @Override
            public void onLoadResource(WebView  view, String  url){
                Logger.d("url="+url);

            }
        });
```

My issue is that if click on the link, my WebViewClient cannot catch it.
But if I change it to `"<a href="http://google.com">anyText</a>"`, then it will work cos the href value is a valid link. 
What I wanted to achieve to is put **any href value** and catch it. I am also NOT visiting any site here. Just want to catch that anyText and do something else.

Answer (score 0):

String url="https://www.google.com"
Did u give Network permission in android manifest?

Comment: its nothing to do with any permission